# errors when installing Python packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

When I am using the `pip-python install package_name` command to install python package, it shows:

```
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip'
command. Collecting package-name
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79:
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning   Could not find a version that satisfies the
requirement package-name (from versions: )   No matching distribution
found for package-name
```

However, I have already **updated the pip version to 8.0.3**. Can any one help with this?

Comment: Try `pip install -U --force-reinstall pip` ([from here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2669)).